# Find duplicates in Postgres with rows referring to the same ID on another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 4 tables on my application, and due to an import error, I have now duplicated references to a specific ID that shouldn't be there.

Each object in these tables should have only one "OTA" of each type (Number, Serial, Condition), however some of them have duplicates.

My tables are structured as follows:

```
OBJECT (O)
ID | OBJECT_TYPE_ID

OBJECT_TYPE_ATTRIBUTES (OTA)
NAME | ID

OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES (OA)
ID | OBJECT_ID

OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES_VALUES (OAV)
ID | REFERENCED_OBJECT_ID
```

Below is where I can see some of these duplicates, using this query:

```
SELECT O."ID" as "Object ID",
       OTA."ID" as "OTA ID",
       OTA."NAME" as "OTA NAME",
       OAV."ID",
       OAV."REFERENCED_OBJECT_ID"
FROM "OBJECT" O
         LEFT OUTER JOIN "OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES" OA ON O."ID" = OA."OBJECT_ID"
         LEFT OUTER JOIN "OBJECT_TYPE_ATTRIBUTES" OTA ON OTA."ID" = OA."OBJECT_TYPE_ATTRIBUTE_ID"
         LEFT OUTER JOIN "OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES_VALUES" OAV ON OA."ID" = OAV."OBJECT_ATTRIBUTE_ID"
WHERE O."ID" = 553322
and OAV."REFERENCED_OBJECT_ID">1;
```

```
 Object ID | OTA ID |      OTA NAME       |  OAV ID  | REFERENCED_OBJECT_ID 
-----------+--------+---------------------+----------+----------------------
    553322 |   9091 | Communication       | 19100141 |               662211
    553322 |   9091 | Communication       | 11094457 |               662211
    553322 |   9092 | Owner               | 11094482 |               771122
    553322 |   9092 | Owner               | 19100147 |               771122
    553322 |   7797 | Product Condition   | 19100142 |               993311
    553322 |   7797 | Product Condition   | 11094387 |               993311
```

I should have only one entry for each type (Communication, Owner, and Product).

I need to identify objects of the same ID (Object ID), same OTA ID, with the same REFERENCE_OBJECT_ID, and remove the one with the lower OAV ID. I have tried to do with CTEs but I'm not being able to iterate through each object individually, and my query is iterating through the tables as a single thing:

```
SELECT "OBJECT_ID"
FROM "OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES"
WHERE "ID" IN (
SELECT "OBJECT_ATTRIBUTE_ID"
FROM (SELECT OAV."ID",
OAV."OBJECT_ATTRIBUTE_ID",
OAV."REFERENCED_OBJECT_ID",
row_number()
OVER (PARTITION BY OAV."REFERENCED_OBJECT_ID" ORDER BY OAV."ID" DESC) AS DUPLICATE
FROM "OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES_VALUES" OAV
JOIN "OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES" OA ON OA."ID" = OAV."OBJECT_ATTRIBUTE_ID"
JOIN "OBJECT_TYPE_ATTRIBUTES" OTA ON OTA."ID" = OA."OBJECT_TYPE_ATTRIBUTE_ID"
JOIN "OBJECT" O ON O."ID" = OA."OBJECT_ID"
where O."OBJECT_TYPE_ID"  = '197'
and OAV."REFERENCED_OBJECT_ID" >1
) AS SUB
WHERE DUPLICATE > 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following query deletes the smallest record. If I understand correctly .

```
SELECT *
FROM
(SELECT O."ID" as "Object ID",
       OTA."ID" as "OTA ID",
       OTA."NAME" as "OTA NAME",
       OAV."ID",
       OAV."REFERENCED_OBJECT_ID",
       row_number()
       OVER (PARTITION BY OAV."REFERENCED_OBJECT_ID" ORDER BY OAV."ID" DESC) AS SEQ
FROM "OBJECT" O
         LEFT OUTER JOIN "OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES" OA ON O."ID" = OA."OBJECT_ID"
         LEFT OUTER JOIN "OBJECT_TYPE_ATTRIBUTES" OTA ON OTA."ID" = OA."OBJECT_TYPE_ATTRIBUTE_ID"
         LEFT OUTER JOIN "OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES_VALUES" OAV ON OA."ID" = OAV."OBJECT_ATTRIBUTE_ID"
WHERE O."ID" = 553322
and OAV."REFERENCED_OBJECT_ID">1) T
WHERE SEQ > 1
```

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly to identify the duplicates within a specific object, but I have thousands of objects in the database and need to identify all objects that have duplicates. So, the query should work for each object individually in the database without specifying o."ID"=<object-id> and bring me all the affected objects. If I remove it from the query you provided, it returns incorrect objects (that don't have duplicates).